# Java - Properties failing to load, but storing properly

Tags: java, properties

I need a configuration file (Properties) for this project I'm working on.
The issue is that the Properties instance fails to load from the file (no exceptions, no visible problems) although it can store properly.

Because I have a defaults HashMap, any property that doesn't exist has it's default value placed in the Properties instance, which then stores everything, so that new properties are seamlessly added when the production server is updated.

I've been tracking this bug for hours, and I can't fix it. I've read dozens of questions here on StackOverflow as well as code examples on other sites. Nothing helped.

The one reason I haven't dropped it already and used the DB instead is that the JDBC driver URL, user and password are stored in that file as well. Notice that the file is being read and written to the hard drive.

Since the defaults system puts stuff in place, even if the file doesn't exist when I try to read, after it's saved it appears, but the next run still won't read anything. I noticed the bug after I changed a setting, and checked the file after a few runs, and to my shock, all values were default.

What's currently happening is the following:
1) No matter if the file is there or not, Properties will not load anything.
2) Since there's nothing in the Properties instance, it is filled with defaults.
3) The instance will now save, overwriting the file with the default values.

Here's all the relevant code:

```
private static Properties getConfig(){
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    File cfgFile = new File("data/titallus.properties");
    try{
        if(cfgFile.createNewFile()){
            System.out.println("Config file not found. A default config file will be created automatically.");
        }
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(cfgFile);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(cfgFile);
        properties.load(reader);
        reader.close();
        System.out.println(properties); // Debug, always prints '{}'
        for(String k : defaults.keySet()){
            if(!properties.containsKey(k)){
                properties.setProperty(k, defaults.get(k));
            }
        }
        properties.store(writer, "Titallus Configuration File");
        writer.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    return properties;
}
```

I have tried everything I could think of, to no avail.
I also have a Properties subclass for multi-language support, which works just fine.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this, or at least, another approach to this?

Comment: What is the stacktrace? You might add it to your question. Then it is easier to help you.

Comment: There's no stack trace. There's not even an exception anywhere... it just silently does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(cfgFile);
```

will be erasing your file before you read from it.

Comment: I feel really stupid right now.
Moved this line further down, right before storing. Fixed it.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 0):

You create a `FileWriter` for the file *before* you load the file, which clears the existing data.